# How to show/hide subplots with checkboxes using plotly off-line

Tags: python, plotly

I am using plotly offline mode to create vertically stacked subplots (1 column and 10 rows) with a common x-axis. I want to have the option to show/hide subplots by using check boxes or drop-down.

Following is the sample code I am using. Basically I need to hide few of the subplots after being rendered. For example, out of the 5 subplots I would like to hide plot2 and plot4. Once hidden only 3 subplots should show. So not just trying to hide the data series as that will still keep the subplot space.

```
import plotly.offline as po
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly import tools

fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=5, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True,
                          subplot_titles=['plot1', 'plot2', 'plot3', 'plot4', 'plot5'])
xval = [i for i in range(10)]
for p in range(5):
    yval = [x**(p+1) for x in xval]
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(mode='lines', x=xval, y=yval, 
                            name='y = x^{}'.format(p+1)), p+1, 1)

fig['layout'].update(title='Test', height=1000, width=1500, showlegend=True, margin=go.Margin(l=150))
po.plot(fig, filename='sample', auto_open=True)
```

Comment: are you using python(just want to confirm) also provide some sample code if possible?

Comment: I am using python.

Comment: I have updated the question with more details and hope this clarifies my question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are not just using the `legend` to toggle the visibility of the traces. Anyway here you go, I use `for loops and if conditions` to generate the necessary objects that make up the dropdown, study the code and let me know if any issues implementing!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.offline as py_offline
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly import tools
py_offline.init_notebook_mode()

trace = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3],
    y=[4, 5, 6]
)

fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=10, cols=1)

for k in range(10):
    fig.append_trace(trace, k+1, 1)

updatemenus=list([
    dict(
        buttons=[],
        direction = 'down',
        pad = {'r': 10, 't': 10},
        showactive = True,
        x = 0,
        xanchor = 'left',
        y = 1.2,
        yanchor = 'top' 
    ),
])

lister = []
for k in range(11):
    lister.append(dict(
        args=['visible', [True for k in range(10)] if k == 0 else [True if (i+1) == k else False for i in range(10)]],
        label='Show Trace ' + str( 'All' if k == 0 else k),
        method='restyle'
    ))

updatemenus[0]['buttons'] = lister

fig['layout']['updatemenus'] = updatemenus


fig['layout'].update(title='subplots')
py_offline.iplot(fig, filename='simple-subplot')
```

[image]

Comment: @Sudheer Does this answer help you?

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am basically looking to completely hide the plot not just the data series which you mentioned can be accomplished using clicking on legend.

Comment: @Sudheer The question seems to state otherwise, please update your question with exact requirements